# How to get list of mounted filesystems on NFS server

Tags: nfs, auditing

For auditing purposes I need to track all remotely mounted NFSv4 filesystems requests on an NFS server (CentOS7) to get both the identity of the mounting system **AND** the filesystem that they mounted.  Using the 'netstat -an' command gets me the identity of the remote system but now I need to know what they mounted.  It also gives no clue as to whether that system unmounted a file and then mounted a different one.

I have seen various references to both 'rmtab' and 'showmount' but they do not show me the currently mounted files and, from what I can see, they are only good for NFSv3 and older mounts.  I have also seen reference to the file /proc/fs/nfsd/clients but cannot see such a file on any of my servers.  Surely the information as to who has what mounted has to be available somewhere in the server even if it is a convoluted path to get there (auditing nfsservctl syscalls worked in olden days.)

Related to that, 'ps' shows me the '[nfsv4.1-svc]' process but I haven't been able to track down who/what/why that is and if it is useful.